# is there any difference between 'enroll in' 'enroll on' and 'enroll for'?

Tags: prepositions, word-difference, phrasal-verbs

When I'm going to say that I will attend some class or some event.

as for the word 'enroll', what is the best preposition to be used after it? 'in', 'on' or 'for'?

Comment: [This article](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181782/whats-the-right-preposition-to-use-with-the-verb-enroll) on another stackexchange site does a good job of answering.

Answer (score 2):

"Enroll" is used to mean that you have registered for something, almost always a class or course of study. So you can be enrolled **in** Differential Calculus or **in** the Engineering Track, or enrolled **at** Some Fancy University. In the first usage (in), you would be on the list of people taking Differential Calculus. In the second usage (at), you would be an active student at Some Fancy University.

Neither would imply that you were actually going to class.

There are a few other uses of enroll, but they are less common. You can sometimes see it used as "add to a list of participants," as in "she enrolled in the company's health insurance program." In those cases, you can use either "joined" or "recruited" instead, depending whether the person added themselves to the list, or someone else added them to the list. "Joined" and "recruited" are more  broadly applicable and will sound right in most contexts, while "enrolled" may not.

"Enrolled" also sometimes has specific meanings to some professions. You will probably never be in a situation where those specific meanings matter. In every case I am aware of though, it means some variation of "write down on a list," sometimes with very specific lists (for example, "enrollment" is the process for creating noble titles in many countries).

Answer (score -1):

First of all, if you want to say that you attended some event, you cannot use "enrol"(British) or "enroll"(American) in order to imply attendance.

However, you want to say you registered to some event, you may you use "on" in such a sentence

> all entrants will be enrolled on new-style courses.

or without a preposition

> 280 new members were enrolled this year

With *in*

*the endowment of religious houses cannot be measured simply by the licences enrolled in chancery.*

With *for*

> I've been enrolled for two years.

Comment: thank you for your kind reply. Could you be so kind as to tell me that how should I use another two prepositions?

Comment: @HenryWang  Sure.

Comment: "Enroll on" in AmE sounds wrong. I would nearly always use "in".

Comment: @Catija Unless you're talking about a date: "I enrolled in college yesterday."

Comment: @Andy I'm not sure what you mean? I wouldn't use "enroll on" in that case.

Comment: @Catija Oops, got it mixed up in my head.  I meant you could say: "I enrolled on Saturday."